# Matplotlib not updating

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
class PlotGUI:
def __init__(self, root, serial):
    self.startPlotting = False
    self.serial = serial
    self.x_vals = []
    self.y_vals = []
    self.currentMaxX = 100
    self.index = count()
    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
    self.mPlot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.mPlot.plot()
    self.mPlot.set_ylim(0, 1100)
    self.mPlot.set_xlim(0, 100)

    self.plotFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Plot")

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.plotFrame)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.plotFrame)
    self.toolbar.update()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.publish()
    #Threading
def publish(self):
    self.plotFrame.grid(sticky="we",row=1, column=0, rowspan=2)
def StartPlotting(self):
    self.startPlotting = True
    self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.Plotting)
    self.t.start()
def StopPlotting(self):
    self.startPlotting = False
def Plotting(self):
    while(self.startPlotting):
        if self.serial.ser.in_waiting:
            self.x_vals.append(next(self.index))
            line = self.serial.ser.readline()
            self.y_vals.append(int(line.decode()))
            #y_vals.append(random.randint(0, 1030))
            #print(int(line.decode()))

            self.mPlot.cla()
            self.mPlot.plot(self.x_vals, self.y_vals)
            current_value = int(repr(self.index)[6:-1])
            if(current_value > self.currentMaxX - 30):
                self.currentMaxX += 30
            self.mPlot.set_ylim(0, 1100)
            self.mPlot.set_xlim(self.currentMaxX - 100, self.currentMaxX)   
        else: self.serial.ser.write(b'S')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The "self.mPlot.plot(self.x_vals, self.y_vals)" in the Plotting function doesn't plot the graph althought both x_vals and y_vals are working correctly.

I have tried to plot the graph in the **init** fuction and it still working fine but I need it to update to show real-time data from the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

canvas.draw() Try this function. It can be used to update a figure that has been changed. It will redraw the current figure.

If the above is not working try this
canvas.flush_events()